# How to implement qDate range selection with qInput?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

How to allow qDate single range selection in qInput?
Below is just an example code of qDate single date selection in qInput. I tried `<q-date v-model="date" range>` but it won't display the selected range in the input box.

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
      <q-input filled v-model="date" mask="date" :rules="['date']">
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
            <q-popup-proxy>
              <q-date v-model="date" ></q-date>
            </q-popup-proxy>
          </q-icon>
        </template>
      </q-input>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      date: '2019/02/01'
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve your goal, note that:

- Use `:model-value` instead of `v-model` in `<q-input>` tag.
- `dateRange` property must be an **object**, **not string**. The object format is:

```
{
  from: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  to: "YYYY-MM-DD"
}
```

Here is my suggestion:

```
<template>
     <q-input filled :model-value="`${dateRange.from} - ${dateRange.to}`">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
            <q-date v-model="dateRange" range>
              <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
              </div>
            </q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    const dateRange = ref({from: '2022/01/01', to: '2022/01/05'})
    return {
      dateRange
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You could take a look on my codepen for better visualization: https://codepen.io/hoangdng-the-sans/pen/QWrWNMq?editors=1010

Comment: could you please take a look at this questions? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/73628267/19890944

Comment: I think you already had the correct answer there 

Comment: I commented under the answer as it was not desired could you please take a look?