# how to implement watcher for q-input q-date (quasar)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have a file "display.vue" which implements a date picker for user to pick the date

```
//display.vue
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
    <q-input filled v-model="date" mask="date" :rules="['date']">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
            <q-date v-model="date">
              <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
              </div>
            </q-date>
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    return {
      date: ref('2019/02/01')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and another file "displayData.js" that filters data in the database

```
//displayData.js
router.get("/", async function (req, res) {
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM database'
  ...
  // display the filtered data
}
```

I want to get the user selected date within displayData.js so each time the user picks a date, displayData.js will query to filter data of that date and display them automatically. How can this be done nicely? Should I update the selected date to URL?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [QDate API](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/date#api--qdate) the component emits `update:model-value` whenever it's value is changed.  You should run a function when that emit happens to rerun your query function:

```html
<q-date v-model="date" @update:model-value="runQuery">
  <div class="row items-center justify-end">
    <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
  </div>
</q-date>
```

```js
methods: {
  runQuery(value) {
    displayData.queryFunctionName(value)
  }
}
```

where `queryFunctionName` is whatever function your `router.get("/")` code lives in (I also just have to say naming your API fetch object `router` is very confusing because that's usually the reserved name for vue-router, which is for actual routing (navigating between pages), not fetching)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to get the user picked date data in displayData.js, not calling the displayData function from display.vue. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: state management with Vuex or Pinia.  put the Date value in a store whenever it's changed.  stores are usually accessible from anywhere in your app by simply importing them into the file you need, that should allow displayData.js to always access the latest Date value.  Quasar does support both [Vuex](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/state-management-with-vuex) and [Pinia](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/state-management-with-pinia)